# mySQL 1046 error when importing wordpress database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, import, mysql-error-1046

I'm moving a locally developed wordpress site to a client's server so I'm trying to export the local database and import it to the server. I exported the .sql file according to the instructions here http://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database but I keep getting this error when importing:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_commentmeta` ;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1046 - No database selected
```

Any help very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like the two other answers say: I wasn't importing the backup file to a particular database. I had to create a new database and upload the file to that, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try sticking a use statement in front of it:

```
USE MyWordpressDBName;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_commentmeta` ;
```

[MySql Use Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html)

Answer (score 2):

You posted a link describing how to **backup** your database. But the problem you have is not with the backup but with the **restore**, so you should look at the instructions on how to restore your database.

Luckily that site also has instructions on how to restore a database from a backup (any guide which only tells you how to backup but not how to restore is IMHO a waste of time). Try following the instructions on this page:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Restoring_Your_Database_From_Backup

In particular notice this command near the end of the tutorial:

```
mysql -h mysqlhostserver -u mysqlusername -p databasename < blog.bak.sql
```

The database name must be specified.