# Mysql 1046 error

Tags: wordpress, import, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1046

I've started a new Wordpress site, and and trying to import a database form a site I had about 3 years ago.
Whenever I click on import, choose the file and set it away, I get this error:

Error

```
SQL query: 

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_commentmeta`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_commentmeta` ;

MySQL said:  
 #1046 - No database selected
```

I've tried a few fixes such as setting the Do not use auto interrupt to off, unticking allow interruption, setting the compatibility mode and changing the character set but nothing seems to work. 
I did import this file into another Wordpress blog about a year ago, so I know it worked then, but it's refusing now.

This is the phpmyadmin version:

```
Server: 109.68.38.30 via TCP/IP
Server version: 5.1.52
Protocol version: 10
User: DM_7850_dbadmin@webserver1.wwwconfig.net
 MySQL charset:  UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

I hope someone will be abel to help here.

Comment: `no database selected` means there's no `use name_of_database` to tell MySQL which DB you're trying to work in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mySQL 1046 error when importing wordpress database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708100/mysql-1046-error-when-importing-wordpress-database)

Comment: I've found the problem, and fixed it! whey hey!
My apologies. I hadn't realised that I was not even logged in properly so the database wasn't there to be imported into. 
Duh...

Answer (score 1):

try following  query to select database and then check

```
USE database_name;
```